# Protocol for semantic version patching: do you bump if dependencies bump?

Tags: dependencies, versioning, semantic-versioning

I have python project that has *pinned dependencies*.  A bug was found in my  package due to a bug in a third-party dependency.  That dependency has released a patch that fixed the bug.  However, according to [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), is it protocol to bump and release a version for every patch release of your pinned dependencies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should update your version number. At the very least you're changing your application in a fashion which *could* alter its behaviour (by utilising different dependency versions) and this needs to be communicated to your application/library users. It may be that you're quite confident that this is a safe change but there's always a *possibility* of a change.

If you're only talking about updating a pinned dependency, with no major no features added and no resulting API differences then you'll only be bumping your 'patch' version number - e.g. from v1.2.3 to v1.2.4. For each release with a new set of dependency pins you'll bump your patch version. Don't worry, you're not going to run out of version numbers ;)

If, on the other hand, you roll up the dependency pin updates with internal backwards-compatible feature changes then you'd bump the 'minor' version number (e.g. 1.2.3 -> 1.3.0), and if you're bundling it with non-backward compatible changes then you'd bump the major version number (1.2.3 -> 2.0.0).

http://semver.org/

Comment: this is a lot of work. if you have a bottom-level module that changes, now you not only have to bump its version (possibly in a manifest AND tag it in git AND remember to push the tags) but you have to do this all the way up the chain.  is this normal, and do tools like [semantic release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) include this in their automation for you?

Comment: Work == BadThing(tm)? When you have two distinct clients who have v1.2.3 of your application where one of them sees BadBehaviour and the other sees GoodBehaviour  then you would normally start looking for how their environmental differences affect the system behaviour. If the root cause of the problem is that some 3rd party library is at a different version then you'd actually be better off knowing that there's a difference between the two applications to begin with, however minor. Yes, this is 'normal'.

Comment: Well... it is a lot of work when you are trying to follow best practices but there is only one use of each dependency and only one "client" and you begin to wonder if it is all worth it. :-)

Comment: Makes total sense.